# Unity3d Click and drag Gizmos

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a bunch of gizmos in the editor, is there a way for me to get the position of a gizmo when it is clicked on?

I have looked at Furr2d, and they have clickable gizmos, but I couldn't find how it was done in their code.

They are doing it with 2d objects, and I will be using 3d objects. I figure that it would basically be the same. At first I thought I would have to create a gameobject for each gizmo, but when using Furr2d, they don't create any extra game objects, so how are they clicking and dragging their gizmos?

Do I have to do it with `ScreenToWorldPoint` or something similar?

Comment: You might also want to check out the [`Handles`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) class.

Comment: So it looks like I could use the `Handles.ArrowCap`, and I would use the position property and that would be the same position as the Gizmo right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to know the position of a default handle you can have a look at [Tools](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tools.html) class.
You should be able to retrieve the desired value.

If you are using your own [Handles](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) then you can just pick the returned value.